# Should I only have 1 table "User" Instead of 2 "Client" and "Worker"

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am worried about the 1 to 1 relationships. I read somewhere that it is bad practice? Also if I'm also worried about performance since I have to do a lot of joins. Please help. If anyone has a better suggestion as to how I can improve this schema, I would really appreciate it. [image]

Comment: why isn't there a type table?

Comment: Can a User Comment on a Photo more than once?  Can a User un-like a Photo?

Comment: Index things correctly and you can relax significantly about index performance

Answer (score 0):

ClientID as separate table isn't necessary, as long one user has **only** one clientId, what you implied by your 1:1 relatiomnship, as it only is an attribute to user table.

But as you want to plan ahead, i would keep it as bridge table, a user can have more than one clientId.

like the user_type table

Comment: I was thinking of making the User a supertype and worker and Client Subtypes  with a usertype  field

Comment: a use can be worker and client, so as long as you don't save much more information in client, you can leave it out, using user as supertspe4 doens't make that much sens, as worker and client i dependent on user. What i find more problematic is photo, as it depends on user and not on worker. that you should fix